# firebase functions: automatically update fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my app I've been able to automatically update a single field using firebase function with this code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();
const path = "ADS/3rVdtNp4RfMXUXFj5ElNOjjcMuT2";
exports.scheduled = functions.pubsub.schedule("* * * * *").onRun((context) => {
  database.doc(path).update({"updateTime": admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()});
  return console.log("Successfully Updated"+admin.firestore.Timestamp.now());
});
```

This works perfectly as in the picture. But it's for a single ID.

[image: Picture]

I however, want to write the code that will apply to all the ID's and any future ID that will that may appear later. I tried the following codes as suggested by someone from this platform almost three years ago. But it didn't help.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();
exports.scheduled = functions.pubsub.schedule("* * * * *").onRun((context) => {
  database.collection("ADS").get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc)=>doc.update({t: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()}));
  });
});
```

I also used this link but I didn't really understand it.
[link to schedule function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions?gen=2nd)

Any help, please?

**Help number 2**

I my app, a user chooses a date in the future. In this case the date is save in the database as Timestamp called `TimestampDeparture`. I want that when the schedule function created `updateTime` (Which is also a timestamp) gets to the chosen timestamp `TimestampDeparture` or even if it's passes it, a field, for example `Total` should be updated to say "COMPLETED".
Can anyone help?

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating your document in each loop iteration you should considerate using [batch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?hl=pt-br#batched-writes) writes.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();

exports.scheduled = functions.pubsub.schedule("* * * * *").onRun(async (context) => {
  const batch = database.batch()
  const {docs} = await database.collection("ADS").get()
  docs.map(doc => {
    const {
      TimestampDeparture,
      Total
    } = doc.data()
    const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
    const higger = now > TimestampDeparture

    batch.set(
      database.doc(`ADS/${doc.id}`),{
         updateTime: higger? TimestampDeparture : now,
         Total: higger? 'COMPLETED' : Total
      }, {
        merge: true
      }
    )
  })

  await batch.commit()
})
```

Comment: Your help was very helpful. I have added an additional question in the edit. Could you please take a look at it

Comment: Ok, let's see if I understand it right: 

When your scheduled function creates the `updateTime` field you want it to use `TimestampDeparture` value but if `updateTime` is higger than `TimestampDeparture` you want to update `Total` value to `COMPLETED`? 

Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want to do

Comment: Guys and ladies, while this answer answers my initial question perfectly, I have other questions to add to this which is an addition to this question. For better understanding of my next question I need to delete the whole question and write it. What should I do? Should I edit it by deleting the whole question or I should ask  a fresh question altogether on a new page?

Comment: @EbenOasis ask a new question and link this to it